# Include, getting "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE)"

Tags: php, private

Hi guys haven done stuff on PHP for quite a while, but I was trying to get an coreDB.php file to have DB information and to be open and close from this file.

Everything is working, but when I try to include this on another file, I allways get the error that I put on the title.

coreDB file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class ConnectionDB
{

    private $dbhost = "localhost";
    private $dbuser = "user";
    private $dbpass = "password";
    private $dbname = "dbname";
    public $conn;

    public function openDbConnection()
    {
        try
        {   
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            echo "Connection Done<br>";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            //var_dump($this->conn);
            //echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function closeDbConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->conn = NULL;
            echo "Connection Over";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            //var_dump($this->conn);
            //echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}?>
```

The other file, clientNewRecord.php, where the previous is include:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("coreDB.php");

echo "this is a test";

private $dbConnect = new ConnectionDB();

$this->dbConnect->openDbConnection();
$this->dbConnect->closeDbConnection();?>
```

I allways get this error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'private' when trying to open the clientNewRecord.php

Isn't when I try to run the $this->dbConnect->openDbConnection(), to go into that file and run from that file?

Comment: `private` is only valid within a class/trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `private $dbConnect = new ConnectionDB();` to `$dbConnect = new ConnectionDB();`. Access Specifiers are allowed only within the class.

Comment: Thanks :D it works now ... this is what I get for not working with php for quite some time

Comment: ha ha ha.. yup mate you are right.. happens, but somehow recovery is possible :).. you are always welcome..

Answer (score 1):

As apokryfos mentioned, you can't declare access (`public`, `private`, `protected`) on variables that aren't a class property (or separately on a class function declaration).

So you would just do:

```
$dbConnect = new ConnectionDB();
$dbConnect->openDbConnection();
$dbConnect->closeDbConnection();
```